# How to insert data for table in mangodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular8

I am trying to insert data for table and show in my page but I do not know how to insert the data and how to get the data to show in the table.If anyone know please help.

```
db.maintable.insert(
{
"id":"1",
"orderno":"19345",
"name" : "tutorialspoint",
"startedate":"21/04/2018",
"enddate":"28/12/2018"
},
{
"id":"2",
"orderno":"12945",
"name" : "tutorialspoint",
"startedate":"01/12/2018",
"enddate":"21/02/2018"
},
{
"id":"3",
"orderno":"12325",
"name" : "tutorialspoint",
"startedate":"21/22/2018",
"enddate":"24/12/2018"
}
)
```

data.service.ts:

```
 getTable() {
    return this._http.get("/api/maintable")
      .map(result => this.result = result.json().data);
  }
```

app.component.ts:

```
this._dataService.getUsers().subscribe(res => this.users = res);
```

app.component.html:

```
<table>
  <thead>

    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Order noo</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Start Date</th>
    <th>End Date</th>

</thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let getdata of maintable">
    <td>{{ getdata.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ getdata.orderno }}</td>
    <td>{{ getdata.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ getdata.startdate }}</td>
    <td>{{ getdata.enddate }}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have made mistake on loop, instead of **maintable** use **result**

```
<tr *ngFor="let getdata of maintable">
```

Comment: How to delete row?

Comment: are you using node js for api?